# Schema.ini doesn't work properly

Tags: ms-access, vba, export, schema, export-to-csv

I'm using Access and I would like to export a table to a .csv file.
I'm using the `DoCmd.TransferText` command to do it.
Since my table gets often updated, I don't want to use export specification, that's why I created a schema.ini to export my data.

The start of my schema.ini file looks like this :

```
ColNameHeader = True
TextDelimiter = None
Format = Delimited(;)
```

The exported csv file looks like this :

FIELD1;FIELD2;FIELD3
"data","data","data"
"data","data","data"

The formatting is only applied on the **first row** (which is the column headers) but **not on the next rows** (which are the actual data).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong please ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: I use only one data source for different kinds of mail merge documents, so I have to allow Access to create a new Schema file each time, so I delete any existing Schema file before proceeding.

```
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
Dim FileNm As String

Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject

FileNm = conAddrPth & "\Schema.ini"
If objFSO.FileExists(FileNm) = True Then
    Kill FileNm
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a procedure that creates the schema.ini file of the table I want to export. I call the procedure before I use the 'DoCmd.TransferText'.